# Can groups of models contain reference to other groups in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I guess that is a pretty straightforward question, if I have something like:

```
class User::Group1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

Can I have a reference to this model in another class that doesn't belong to group 1?

Comment: yes of course you can, its a model like the others

Answer (score 0):

i dont know whether i am answering the question.but in a model namespacing environment,you can refer any model using `class` name ...such as

```
class Statistics::Request < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :session, :class_name => "Statistics::Session"
end

class Statistics::Session< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :requests, :class_name => "Statistics::Request"
end
```

HOPE IT HELPS... :)